# Get all images ID that exist in the database and display them (MySQL\PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've read all about this in other questions asked here at stackoverflow but none have gave me answers to my situation.
Here is what i have:

- Database of the Images ID and Location. (database has two columns ID and URL) the ID is incremental and same name as the image name. so in the database it shows as follows:
  [image: Database Overview]

now my question is how can i retrieve those images from the database?
I know how to display them in HTML using the php echo.
but my problem is how to get them out of the database in order?
I'm thinking about something maybe like while(still images id)
Or I can use count of the number of rows then go one by one calling them (which i think is too heavy)

Any help would be great figuring this one out!

Thank you :)

Comment: i still dont understand what you want. did you mean `select * from table order by ID ASC` ? it gets all the id and url in order

Comment: Take a look at the [PHP PDO documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php). Example #2 is basically what you want to do. It shows you how to fetch the results and loop through them. As far as ordering, simply add an `ORDER BY id` clause at the end of your SELECT statement.

Comment: the images aren't in the database, only the links to them are

Comment: yes exactly only the links.

Comment: would it work if i only inserted the ID in the database, and when i want to display the images, i only get the number of rows (number of existing ID) and then using a for loop i echo the url (which is static) with the dynamic Id that changes?

Comment: are the images inside your directory or from outside of your web?

Comment: inside my directory therefor the path is static

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to connect to the database and query it for the images in your table. (tbl_name must be replaced by the name of your MySQL table containing the images)

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT URL from tbl_name ORDER BY URL");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)) {
    echo $row['URL'];
}
```

See the excellent tutorials on W3Schools for details: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: The [`mysql_` functions are deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)  as of PHP 5.5...Using them is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT URL FROM TableName";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["URL"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually, it is a good idea to include some explanation as to how the code answers the question in addition to bare code.